# Package 'libudev0' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04

```
abhishek x86_64-linux-gnu $ ls -l |grep libudev  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Jun 27 15:11 libudev.so.0 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 May 12 15:09 libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  126840 May 12 15:09 libudev.so.1.6.4
abhishek x86_64-linux-gnu $ sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/reditr_amd64.deb                               [sudo] password for abhishek: 
(Reading database ... 313009 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../Downloads/reditr_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking reditr (3.0.0.0) over (3.0.0.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of reditr:
 reditr depends on libudev0 (>= 147); however:
  Package libudev0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package reditr (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 reditr
abhishek x86_64-linux-gnu $ sudo apt-get install libudev0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libudev0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libudev0' has no installation candidate
```

I am trying to install reditr, there is dependency of libudev0 which doesn't exits in repos. Following https://www.reddit.com/r/reditrbugs/comments/3lzmhq/bug_with_reditr_on_ubuntu_1504_libudev147/ I created a syslink, this doesn't work.

Comment: `libudev0` is an Ubuntu 12.04 package. http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/libudev0

Comment: How do I solve the issue and install it?

Comment: I googled around and found https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/1ev7up/any_luck_using_reditr/ that said http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/fix-google-chrome-cant-be-installed-in.html should help. Try downloading the .deb file in the last link and install it using `sudo dpkg -i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download `libudev0` from:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise-updates/amd64/libudev0/download

And install it by:
`sudo dpkg -i libudev0[verion-and-stuff].deb`

And then install `reditr.deb`